# Redirect Magento2 404 page to the register page

Tags: customer, 404-page, registration, custom-field, redirect-url

I'm using Magento 2 to create my site. I want to dynamically assign a sponsor to the register of a new customer. I had create a customer custom field named nickname on the database. In practice I want to provide a link such as http://mywebsite.net/John1 where John1 is the nickname of the sponsor. The system will give an error not finding the requested page. I want to edit 404 page and redirect for the registering page with the sponsored nickname on it.
I create a link:

```
http://mywebsite.net/John1
```

The 404 page will process the URL and catch the string John1 and assign to the field nickname in a way that the registering page should be such as:

```
Sponsor: John1
Name:__________________
E-mail: _______________
Etc.
```

Could someone help me on this hard task? At least some guidelines how to start would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this requirement, you have to understand  two things:

- Magento own routing process.Checkout the blog
  https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-routing.html
- And how to create a custom router at **See
  how to create a custom router. Check out the blog
  https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-router-in-magento-2.html**

Using this two, you can achieve your requirement.

Use of custom route means to point a custom URL `http://example.com/index.php/mytesturl/` to Magento **own routing** `http://example.com/index.php/front_name/controller/action/` .

A good example of a custom router that is [Magento own CMS module](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Page/View.php#L7-L9)

Suppose you have created two cms pages from admin:

One is about us and it is identifier is `about-us` and its id is 5.

Then if you hit the url `www.example.com/about-us` then you can see the content is server from admin `about-us` cms page. If you debug that page `www.example.com/about-us` and then you will find that the page is rendered from Action class

> [Magento\Cms\Controller\Page\View](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Page/View.php#L7-L9)

Internally,
`www.example.com/about-us` is requesting the page `www.example.com/cms/page/view/page_id/5`.

You can check this point logic is manage fro router class
[Magento\Cms\Controller\Router](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Router.php#L6-L11) , the businesses logic of cms page routing is managed from here.

```
$page = $this->_pageFactory->create();
$pageId = $page->checkIdentifier($identifier, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
if (!$pageId) {
    return null;
}
$request->setModuleName('cms')->setControllerName('page')->setActionName('view')->setParam('page_id', $pageId);
$request->setAlias(\Magento\Framework\Url::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS, $identifier)
```

***So, you need to implement the same type of business routing logic for your requirement.***

Where `http://mywebsite.net/John1`  internally request to url

> ```
> http://mywebsite.net/{customFrontenname}/{Mycontrollername}/{MyActionName}/customer_id/{CustomerId}
> ```

At **Custom router check  request path** `$request->getPathInfo()`, is match with a **customer nickname** .